# Checking for Prerequsites before Installing Application

Tags: installation, clickonce, setup-deployment, bootstrapper

I am developing an application. I'm using ClickOnce of Microsoft to install my application on user's computer. Now I want to check for prerequsites if they are installed and ready to use. So how can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Refer to the documentation on [How to: Install Prerequisites with a ClickOnce Application](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8st7th1x%28v=vs.100%29.aspx), in particular the quote:

> When publishing a ClickOnce application, you can choose a set of prerequisite components to be packaged along with your application. At installation time, a check will be performed for each prerequisite to determine if it already exists; if not it will be installed prior to installing the ClickOnce application.